# '=' expected near 'Jumpscare"

Tags: lua

```
local Jumpscare = 0

function onUpdate()
    setProperty('cpuControlled', false)
    setProperty Jumpscare = 1
    return
end

function onUpdate()
    if Jumpscare = 1 then
        playSound('PIRACY_IS_ILLEGAL!')
    end
    
end
```

code does not work
please help anyone

i tried playing a sound over and over again on a cpuControlled event but it just dosent work

Comment: You have two syntax errors: (1) `setProperty Jumpscare = 1` - why are you prefixing the assignment with `setProperty`? (2) `if Jumpscare = 1 then` - you can't use a statement (set `Jumpscare` to `1`) as an expression (is `Jumpscare` equal to `1`). Please get a linter like Luacheck and/or a decent editor to catch syntax errors right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you compare something in Lua and many other languages, especially when you want to know if they're equal, then you should use a double equal sign:

```
if Jumpscare == 1 then
    playSound('PIRACY_IS_ILLIGAL')
end
```

This is because "=" are used to set a variable to a certain value. In english your code says:

> if ... Btw Jumpscare is equal to one. ... then

Instead, you would want it to say:

> if Jumpscare is equal to one, then...

Hence the "==" !
Have a good day and remember to use "==" when comparing values :D

Comment: "Btw Jumpscare is equal to one" - I would rather phrase this as if "set jumpscare to one"

Comment: Uhhh it still gives me the error and i tried changing stuff like you said
local Jumpscare = 0

`function onUpdate()
    setProperty('cpuControlled', false)
    setProperty Jumpscare == 1
    return
end`


if Jumpscare == 1 then
    playSound('PIRACY_IS_ILLEGAL!')
end

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with you code, I'll see if I can help with that.

Comment: once you activate botplay which is cpucontrolled i want to play the 'PIRACY_IS_ILLEGAL' sound

Comment: I know very little about Psych engine. I would assume that setProperty Jumpscare = 1 is wrong, try removing the setProperty on that line, also you’re creating two functions with the same name, Idk how lua computes that but humanly I don’t get what the point is. Hope that can help you :D Have a great day and good luck fixing that

Comment: Huge respect to you ill try and see what can i do

Comment: Hey uh it still didint work however i wont annoy you anymore. Ill try to fix it myself somehow